# Inkscape undo(Ctrl+Z) keyboard shortcut is not working properly

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell, inkscape

In Inkscape if I try to undo something with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it does nothing. However if I try to undo it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> shortcut it works just fine. I believe that this might be because in my keyboard the <kbd>Y</kbd> and the <kbd>Z</kbd> keys are switched (compared to an english one). But I have my keyboard layout set up properly(I hope) because for example if I type Z in the terminal it types Z and not Y.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME Shell 3.18.5

What might cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: the program registers the key pressed not the letter assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the undo shortcut to Ctr+Y makes the Ctrl+Z shortcut work.